# Attribute error for web crawler

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-crawler, urllib

When running the following code:

```
import urllib
import re
from urllib import request
import webbrowser

#email pattern
r'[\w._(),:;<>]+@[\w._(),:;<>][.]\w+'

# url pattern
r'\w\w\w[.]\w+[.]\w+'

html = urllib.request.urlopen('somelinkthatistoolongforstackoverflow')

#find all websites

websites = re.findall(r'http://www[.]\w+[.]\w+',str(html.read()))
print(websites)

#find all emails

emails = re.findall(r'[\w._(),:;<>]+@[\w._(),:;<>][.]\w+',str(html.read()))
print(emails)

#sort through websites and find other links

for i in websites:
    y = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
    x = re.findall(r'http://www[.]\w+[.]\w+',str(y.read()))
    websites.append(x)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Notice the AttributeError.  What can I do about this?  I am using the urllib module and the regex (regular expressions) module.  This is in python 3.3.0.  Can anyone help me with this?  If you can help me please post below.  This is meant to be a web crawler to find as many links and email adresses as I can.  Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *extend* `websites`:

```
websites.extend(x)
```

because `x` is itself a list.

You currently *append* the list of matched websites, so at some point you'll pass that list as `i` from the `for` lop to `urllib.request.urlopen()` which then tries to treat it as a `Request` object, since it is certainly not a string, the other valid option.